# Find relative extrema of $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \beta_k (x-\alpha_k)^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Find relative extrema  of $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \beta_k (x-\alpha_k)^2,$$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha_k,\; \beta_k \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \beta_k\neq 0$.

I know that $f'(x)=2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \beta_k(x-\alpha_k)$, but I have no idea how to solve the equation $f'(x)=0$. Does anyone have an Idea?

Comment: Typo, you wanted $(x-\alpha_k)^2$. And setting the derivative equal to $0$ you get a linear equation.

Comment: $f$ is simply a line, and by your condition that the sum of the $\beta_k$ is not $0$, the slope of the line is not $0$. The extrema should be $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.

Comment: How did everybody know what the question was supposed to be?

Comment: @robjohn: The last sentence :-).

Answer (score 1):

Is your function $f$ supposed to be $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \beta_k (x-\alpha_k)^2\ ?$$

If so, the solution to $f'(x) = 0$ is $$x = \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \beta_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n \beta_k}$$ since this is just a linear equation in $x$.